# This may seem like a duplicate but I can not find an answer. phpmailer error code but script works

Tags: phpmailer

So I have a script Im working on that among other things loops through a folder and add all picture in the folder to the email body. I have it working just fine but it shows this error every time I run it

```
PHP Notice:  file_get_contents(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory in /home/fromituc/public_html/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 3358
```

Please any ideas, here is the code I come up with that embeds the pictures for me.

```
$newFiles = scandir("$mypath");
foreach($newFiles as $files19) {    
$cid_name= (mt_rand(10,99));   
$body.="<img alt='PHPMailer' src='cid:$cid_name'> ";
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("$mypath$files19", "$cid_name", "$files19");
      }
```

as stated, the code works but always shows the error. The email sent has the pictures embedded in the body as wanted .

Answer (score 1):

No one has answered yet, but in case someone else needs this later. I found an answer.

```
$arrFiles = array();
$iterator = new FilesystemIterator("$mypath");
 
foreach($iterator as $entry) {
    $arrFiles[] = $entry->getFilename();
    
$cid_name= (mt_rand(10,99));   
$body.="<img alt='PHPMailer' src='cid:$cid_name'> ";
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("$entry", "$cid_name", "$entry");
          }
```

This code allows me to scan a folder of Pictures and then add them to the body of my email.

Comment: $mypath/ is of course the path to the folder